If a system can non-trivially write a self-interpreter, is it necessarily Turing complete?
We've all seen the brainf*ck interpreter written in brainf*ck, or the game of life running in the game of life.
Does the ability for a language/program/system to stimulate itself necessarily make it Turing complete?

No.  Consider the following system: no matter what the text of the program is or the input to the program, the system outputs the number 42.  (If you prefer, think of this of a programming language whose syntax allows only a single operation: print_42_and_halt().)
Then it is easy to write a program in this language to simulate any other program in this language.
However, this language is not Turing-complete.

But what about "non-trivially" from the question?

@DmitriUrbanowicz, Good point, I didn't see that the question in the title does not match the question in the body. I don't see the word "non-trivially" in the body of the question, and generally I go by what is in the body of the question, so if "non-trivially" is an important criteria, I hope they'll include it in the body of the question and clarify what they mean by that.
